# Make Laravel Homestead 2.0 work with custom 32bit vagrant box

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have an older laptop that doesn't support virtualisation, meaning that I cannot use the box suggested by the laravel homestead docs. ( http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead )

As such, I have forked & modified the laravel/settler repository to make use of the 32bit Utopic image ( https://github.com/twoSeats/homestead32utopic/commit/4463b27888ff027299753f27af2929e09d5493a5 ).

I managed to create and provision the image using my new settler repository, but I can't for the life of me get homestead 2.0 to use it on execution of the

```
'homestead up'
```

command.
Any ideas anyone?

#### EDIT:

- 'homestead up' still attempts to pull down & use the official vagrant box ( laravel/homestead ).
- what i did was actually provision a 32bit Utopic box locally using a modified version of 'laravel/settler'
- I would like to now use the Homestead CLI application to manage and use the box I now have locally.
- I don't know how to get the CLI app to use the box I already have provisioned and have available within virtualbox.
- Is there a tutorial already available for this?
- Or is there a 32bit homestead box available? that is tested and working?

Unfortunately the 32bit homestead offerings available are up to 8+ months old ( https://github.com/buonzz/homestead32 & https://github.com/antoniofrignani/laravel-homestead-settler-32 ) and since I wish to develop for updated specs & use the current homestead 2.0 features; they will just not do anymore.

Comment: We don't know what error you're getting or what/how this isn't functioning - what happens when you homestead up?

Comment: let me clarify my issues in the question

Comment: @fideloper tried to explain further, hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: This gist explains how to "build" the latest homestead box using 32 bit Ubuntu. https://gist.github.com/noeldiaz/0f9a2583a41579878764